# Rsnapshot multiuser

Tags: root, multiuser, rsnapshot

I have setup a server.
In this server I have made several users and those people are logging in on a regular basis.

I want to offer everyone to setup their own rsnapshot, so that they can take regular backups of their folders.

The problem with that is that the rsnapshot config file, in /etc/rsnapshot.conf
is a root only file and stored in /etc.

Is there any way for me to give each user their own rsnpashot.conf file so that they can setup rsnapshot to store their directories back in time?

Comment: You can call `rsnapshot -c <file>` to use an alternate config file; maybe this could help (see `man snapshot` for more hints).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is a very sound idea.

1. If rsnapshot is run as root, then you should configure it
2. If rsnapshot is run as `<username>` then they can configure it. They can achieve this by using their own crontab entry.

I would opt for the first option.

But to answer your question specifically, remember the configuration file can be specified using `-c <filename>` option. So potentially you could start it specifying a user specific config file, which they own and administer eg.

```
/usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /home/<username>/.rsnapshot.conf daily
```

Comment: so how do i get this rsnapshot.conf file started for a given user? i tried running that command but there is not .rsnapshot.conf file in the home directory.

Comment: You said "I want them to setup their own rsnapshot" so let them write their own config. If you want to give them a template, then do that. see `man adduser` and add your starter config into  `/etc/skel` You can simplify their config by including your own master configuration.